# Remove varargs object arrays with ProGuard

Tags: java, android, logging, proguard, android-proguard

I'm trying to remove the logs from my app using ProGuard. I follow up this [documentation page](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/examples#logging), but unfortunately I was unable to remove the Object[] created by the use of varargs.

---

#### Java Code

My custom logger example looks like this:

```
public final class MyLogger {

    private static final StringBuilder V_STRING_BUILDER = new StringBuilder(0);

    private MyLogger() {
        //no instance
    }

    public static void v(@NonNull String tag, @NonNull String method, @NonNull Object... message) {
        final String processedMessage;

        synchronized (V_STRING_BUILDER) {
            processedMessage = createMessage(V_STRING_BUILDER, message);
        }

        Log.v(tag.concat(method), processedMessage);
    }

    @NonNull
    private static String createMessage(@NonNull final StringBuilder builder,
                                        @NonNull final Object... messages) {

        builder.setLength(0);

        //noinspection ForLoopReplaceableByForEach
        for (int i = 0, size = messages.length; i < size; i++) {
            builder.append(messages[i]);
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

And I log information like this:

```
MyLogger.v(TAG, "myMethod", "The list of parameter");
```

---

#### Proguard File

```
-optimizations code/removal/advanced
-optimizationpasses 5
-allowaccessmodification

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
    public static int wtf(...);
}

-assumenoexternalsideeffects class java.lang.StringBuilder {
    public java.lang.StringBuilder();
    public java.lang.StringBuilder(int);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder(java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(java.lang.Object);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(java.lang.StringBuffer);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(char[]);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(char[], int, int);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(boolean);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(char);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(int);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(long);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(float);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(double);
    public java.lang.String toString();
}

-assumenoexternalreturnvalues public final class java.lang.StringBuilder {
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(java.lang.Object);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(java.lang.StringBuffer);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(char[]);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(char[], int, int);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(boolean);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(char);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(int);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(long);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(float);
    public java.lang.StringBuilder append(double);
}

-assumenosideeffects class com.asousa.testing.proguard.MyLogger {
    public static void v(...);
}
```

---

#### Final Result

When I reverse engineer my APK I can check from my example that the following instruction is kept in my source code:

```
new Object[1][0] = "The list of parameter";
```

Although the log is not written to the device's logcat, the object array is kept.

Is there any way to tell ProGuard to these arrays also?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `MyLogger` instead of `Log`, so you need to add rules for `MyLogger` at first.